# Wave equation as a consequence of Newton's second law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, string

How the linear wave equation is a direct consequence of Newton's second law applied to any element of a string carrying a travelling wave?

Comment: Try to analyse a small infinitesimal length of the string. Draw its free body diagram and use Newton's second law. You will surely get something out of that.

Answer (score 1):

The wave equation is not a consequence of analyzing a vibrating string.  But rather analyzing a string leads to a result that fits the wave equation. Analysis of many other situations lead to results that fit the wave equation

See

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/110842/45664

[Derivation of 1D wave equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/395101/45664)

In the second reference is a way to derive the wave equation using only $f(x-ct)$ and $f(x+ct)$, not requiring any physical situation at all.